# Biological significance of network parameters

Tags: biological-networks

I am currently working on networks and I have calculated various parameters for the network like diameter, average path length, average eccentricity, radiality etc. Could someone guide me to some articles I could read as to what biological significance these parameters hold with regard to a biological network (gene regulatory network). Example, what does a small diameter, radiality etc say with regard to the biological property of the network. On research I could only find [one article](https://www.intechopen.com/books/new-frontiers-in-graph-theory/centralities-based-analysis-of-networks) which could be of some help. Thanks

Edit: I understand that this question has been identified as being too broad but all I require are links to articles that could perhaps guide me to an appropriate solution. Perhaps, the answer can be limited to how does a large network affect a radiality value affect a biological network?

Edit2: Its a cluster from a bigger network, is bipartite in nature, consisting of Transcription factors and genes with a size of 361 nodes. My aim is to check if the clusters are all different from each other and determine if there are significant differences between each cluster. The question was all about what biological inferences can be drawn from network parameters like diameter, radiality etc. For example, a network with low diameter means that network information is passed faster between even the furthermost nodes meaning pathways in that network could have genes with functions that require quick actions, say genes that govern sensory perceptions like reflex actions.

Comment: As it currently stands, I think your question is too broad. If you can focus on a single parameter though, perhaps you will have more success in obtaining a response.

Comment: You will have to limit this to what sort of question you are trying to answer with that network. You might want to use all of these features or none of them. You should also explain what size of network this is and whether it was built using one gene, many, the entire genome or what.